# Lomb Scargle phase

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics, fft, astropy

Is there any way I can extract the phase from the Lomb Scargle periodogram? I'm using the LombScargle implementation from `gatspy`.

```
from gatspy.periodic import LombScargleFast

model = LombScargleFast().fit(t, y)
periods, power = model.periodogram_auto()
frequencies = 1 / periods
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(frequencies, power)
plt.show()
```

Power gives me an absolute value. Any way I can extract the phase for each frequency as I can for a discrete fourier transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lomb-Scargle method produces a periodogram, i.e., powers at each frequency. This is in order to be able to be performant, compared to directly least-squares fitting a sinusoidal model. I don't know about `gatspy`, but `astropy` does allow you to compute the best phase for a specific frequency of interest, see http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/stats/lombscargle.html#the-lomb-scargle-model  . I imagine doing this for many frequencies is many times slower than computing the periodogram.

-EDIT-

The docs outline moved to: 
https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/timeseries/lombscargle.html

Comment: Link is unfortunately broken (as of 2019-08-08)

Answer (score 0):

let's consider that you're looking for a specific frequency fo. Then the corresponding period can be given by P = 1/fo.
We can define a function, as in below:

```
def phase_plot(t,period):
    #t is the array of timesteps
    phases = (time/period)%1.
```

this will give you all the phases for that particular frequency of interest.